# Order if Increment and Evaluation of Array in C with Shorthand Notation

Tags: c, arrays

I have written a small code to understand the order of increment and evaluation of an array with the shorthand increment notation within the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int j;
int array[500];

void main() {
array[0]=3;
array[1]=3;
array[2]=3;

while (j<10){
        array[j++]=7;
        printf("value of array[j]  after %d\n",array[j]);
    }
}
```

It appears that the increment is occurred "after" the evaluation of the array so `array[j]` is assigned `7` and then `j` is incremented. Is it always the case the evaluation happens before the increment in such shorthand `array[j++]` notations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the postfix `++` is the original value of its operand, and the operand is incremented as a side effect.

This is in contrast to the prefix `++` operator:

```
array[++j]=7;
```

Which evaluates to the *incremented* value of its operand, and again the operand is incremented as a side effect.

In both cases, the side effect of incrementing is not guaranteed to happen until the next sequence point, which *loosely speaking* means the next statement.

That means if you attempt to do something like this:

```
x = ++j + j;
```

It causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because `j` is being read and written in the same statement.

Comment: when you say evaluates to incremented value, say j before the loop is `0`, will it evaluate to `array[1]` which is incremented value of `j` and then `j` will be incremented to `2` as a side effect?

Comment: so essentially `j` being incremented twice in a single loop?

Comment: @gfdsal The increment only happens once.  If `j` is 0 before the statement, it will be 1 after, and `array[++j]` evaluates to `array[1]`.

Comment: thats my concern, as I assign `array[1]=7`, but when I print `array[1]` it gives me old value when I execute the code above. I am printing after the assignment is done.